# application.css for different layouts how to set correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails application i've got several layouts and for each I want to load special CSS how can I do this?

at the moment application.css looks like this:

```
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require filechooser
//= require bootstrap-switch.min
//= require jquery.datetimepicker
//= require fancybox2_1_5/jquery.fancybox
//= require style
*= require_self
*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using different layouts for different controllers, then you can use your special **css** or **js** files directly in your layouts by adding a method to your `ApplicationHelper` as follow:

```
def controller_stylesheet_link_tag
  if params[:controller] == "foo"
    stylesheet_link_tag 'foo'
  else
    stylesheet_link_tag 'bar'
  end
end
```

Then, add this helper method to your layouts like `application.html.erb` -

```
 <%= controller_stylesheet_link_tag %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to use a specific JS/CSS for file for each layout (when applicable).

For example, `app/layouts/application.html.erb` would have your `application.css`, like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
```

Whereas `app/layouts/admin.html.erb` will have `admin.css`:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'admin' %>
```

Using Sprockets 3 or later, you can even use index files in the directories to keep things organized.
`app/assets/stylesheets/admin/index.css` will be available as `admin.css`. See [Index Files are proxies for folders](https://github.com/rails/sprockets#index-files-are-proxies-for-folders) for more info.

Comment: when I do this, the problem is precomiliation don't work

Comment: @Felix – this is a different issue. You need to specifically tell Sprockets what files should be available in the `config.assets.precompile` list. Depending on your version of Rails, that will be configured in `config/initializers/assets.rb` or `config/application.rb`

Comment: Or, use the `link` directive https://github.com/rails/sprockets#the-link-directive `//= link 'admin.js'` or `//= link 'admin.css'` – you may have to play with the paths to get this working.